Serialize a nested object with Django Rest Framework
I'm currently trying to serialize the following object into the models listed below, the current relationship is
A Category has many quizzes, a quiz belongs to one category, while containing many questions, a question belongs to a quiz, while containing many choices. Any help would be much appreciated!
This is the last error I have been receiving:
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field choices on serializer QuestionSerializer.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the RelatedManager instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'choices'.
{
    "category": 1,
    "title": "Basic Java",
    "question": {
        "title": "Boolenas",
        "text" : "adafasad",
        "correct_words": [],
        "choice_type": "SINGLE",
        "choices": [
            {
                "text": "asdadawd",
                "is_correct": true
            },
            {
                "text": "adwasda",
                "is_correct": false
            },
            {
                "text": "asdawd",
                "is_correct": false
            }
        ]
    }
}

The models are the following:
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
    
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Quizzes'

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='placeholder')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    correct_words = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255), blank=True, null=True)
    # choice_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, related_name='questions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    
class Choice(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='choices', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

And lastly these are my serializers:
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields= ('id', 'title')
        
    def validate(self, data):
        if Category.objects.filter(title=data.get('title')).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Category with this name already exists.")
        return data
            
        
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['text', 'is_correct']

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'correct_words', 'choices']

class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question = QuestionSerializer(source='questions')

    class Meta:
        model = Quiz 
        fields = ['category', 'title', 'question', 'created_date']
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        category_data = validated_data.pop('category')
        question_data = validated_data.pop('questions')
        choices_data = question_data.pop('choices')

        quiz = Quiz.objects.create(category=category_data, title=validated_data['title']) 
        
        question = Question.objects.create(quiz=quiz, **question_data)
        
        for choice_data in choices_data:
            choice = Choice.objects.create(question=question, **choice_data)

        return quiz

I would guess the problem is when I try to serialize back the objects into the response, since the objects are being saved into the database (or this could just be DJANGO not rolling back the transactions)
As I said before, any help would be much appreciated!
